# Safe to empty log_civicrm_group? 4.7

Tags: logs

Dealing with an old 4.7 site on Drupal 7, has a huge (21 million row) log_civicrm_group table which I can see has been flagged as a bug in later versions - am I safe to empty/truncate that table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's just for logging - you can truncate. If you think you might need the logs later you can back up just that table first and store it somewhere.

Comment: ok, thanks very much!